# How to check how much time node-cron is taking for executing cron-job

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, node-cron

I want to check how much time cron job is taking to execute the cron job process for that particular cron job.

After which if cron-job is taking more than 10 minutes to execute that process then that particular cron-job should be stopped and rest cron job should process as normal.

I am using node-cron package for cron job.

In below code I want to get how much time it takes to executes that process if it it is more than 10 minutes then in setTimeout() function i can use task.stop() method of cron to stop that cron job.

`var task = cron.schedule('0 1 * * *', () => {
   console.log('Runing a job at 01:00')
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to set a timeout to cancel a process if it exceeds 10 minutes of runtime. The best answer would depend on what kind of activity the process is doing. If you are using the `child_process` module to spawn another process you can start with an example from the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_class_childprocess) which kills the child process after 2 seconds and adjust it to your needs:

```
'use strict';
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

const subprocess = spawn(
  'sh',
  [
    '-c',
    `node -e "setInterval(() => {
      console.log(process.pid, 'is alive')
    }, 500);"`
  ], {
    stdio: ['inherit', 'inherit', 'inherit']
  }
);

setTimeout(() => {
  subprocess.kill(); // Does not terminate the Node.js process in the shell.
}, 2000);
```

Comment: This is great solution. Thank you so much for the help